# Android application without GUI

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, android-wifi

I have been developing a simple application without UI using broadcast receiver.

The app doesn't contain any ACTIVITIES.

I have given necessary permissions.

I took the code from this url:http://developerandro.blogspot.in/2013/09/check-internet-connection-using.html

The app shows a toast "Not connected to internet" when I click change wifi state. It's working correctly.

But my question is There is an activity registered in my manifest file which I don't have. So I delete those lines from my manifest. Then no toasts are shown and I checked the logs too. No output on changing wifi state.

Why this happened? Please help me guys...

Here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.broadcast_internetcheck"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.broadcast_internetcheck.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.broadcast_internetcheck.NetworkChangeReceiver"
            android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my Broadcastreceiver class:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

  @Override
     public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

         String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
          /*Above line will return the status of wifi */
         Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     }
}
```

Comment: you mean you are not able to connect to internet ?? is that so?

Comment: that's not my situation, I need a simple toast when I change my wifi state.

Comment: So you want to make toast button, i don't your code but i'll make a simple Toast button for you?

Comment: As your question, it's because the activity hold the showing Toast function, when the activities hasn't been launched, it will not show Toast. You can write a service to do so without any activity.

Comment: @user2652394 the toast is shown from BroadcastReceiver class, in onReceive method.

Comment: @user2652394 u r not following me. The above code working correctly. If took off the lines <activity>...</activity>, no toast are shown.

Comment: @user2652394 bcoz, I have no activities to register in the manifest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to create a dummy activity for a Service which will be triggered in the `onCreate()` of the dummy, maybe a non-UI with `finish()` .

Without that the required implementation is not possible, esp above Android 3.1.

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols
[Run only a background service when application start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064132/run-only-a-background-service-when-application-start)
[Start android application without activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497885/start-android-application-without-activity)
http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html

And for more on Service:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `service` instead. But showing `Toast` through `service` bit complicated instead you can show `notification` through `service` for **No Internet Connection**.

Comment: can u tell me how to notify using service? That'd be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603884/android-notify-from-my-alarm-class/21604104#21604104

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any activity check this answer. Actually you would have to create service for this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909683/launch-android-application-without-main-activity-and-start-service-on-launching)

Comment: Yes, I knew about services. but there should not be any activities.

Answer (score 0):

Create a transparent activity. Launch the toast while the activity is active and immediately finish the activity.